# Shiny: How to properly include Shiny HTML

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to include in a Shiny app an interactive document generated from a Rmd. Problem is the Rmd includes two Shiny apps.

This is the .Rmd

````
# myInteractiveDocument.Rmd

...

```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}

  shinyAppDir('shiny_app_dir1',   
                options=list(width= "100%", height=700))
```

...

```{r, echo=FALSE}
shinyAppDir('shiny_app_dir2')
```
````

and this is the outer Shiny app

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

...
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot"),
         includeHTML("intro.html")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

...

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I proceeded in this way:

I compiled the Rmd document with

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('myInteractiveDocument.Rmd')"
```

and moved it to the same folder of the outer app.

When I run it from RStudio everything works. But then when I moved it on a Ubuntu server I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

raised at this line

```
var dynamicResults = results.filter(".html-widget-output");
```

of `data:application/x-javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to load the apps as objects. For example

````
# myInteractiveDocument.Rmd

...

```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}

ui1 = source( "path/to/app1/ui.R", local = TRUE )$value
server1 = source( "path/to/app1/server.R", local = TRUE )$value
server( input, output, session )
ui1
```

...

```{r, echo=FALSE}
ui2 = source( "path/to/app2/ui.R", local = TRUE )$value
server2 = source( "path/to/app2/server.R", local = TRUE )$value
server2( input, output, session )
ui2
```
````

Note that `source( ..., local = TRUE )` is basically just like copy/pasting, so the input/output ids of the two apps and the `rmd` must not collide in order for this to work.